# Elementary inequalities for polynomial functions

Tags: calculus

Let

$$f(t) = \sum_{j= 1}^{n} jb_jt^{j-1}\,\,,\,\;t \in \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}\;\;\; \text{an open bounded set.}$$

Is it true that there exists a constant $D$ such that $|f(t)| \le D(1 + |t|^{n-1})$?

Then, is it true that $||f||_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)} \le D(1 + ||t||_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)}^{n-1})$?

I suppose the answer is yes to both questions, can you help me to find a proof?

Comment: Do you mean $|f(t)| \le D(1+|t|^{n-1})$?

Comment: yes, thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any $t^{j-1}$ in the sum satisfies $|t^{j-1}| \le 1$ if $|t|\le1$ and $|t^{j-1}| \le |t^{n-1}|$ if $|t|\ge1$. In particular, we always have $|t^{j-1}| \le 1 + |t|^{n-1}$. Therefore (by the triangle inequality)
$$
|f(t)| \le \sum_{j=1}^n |jb_jt^{j-1})| \le \sum_{j=1}^n j|b_j|(1+|t|^{n-1}),
$$
showing that you can take $D = \sum_{j=1}^n j|b_j|$.